# What command "service xyz start" will run to start the service

Tags: linux, service

How one can see what command `service` will use to run to start a service? I want this **without** actually starting or having started [1] the service (`service xyz start`) for 2 reasons:

- I might want to inspect the command line arguments before actually starting the service
- If the command fails to start for some reason, I would like to see the command that caused the problem. I can probably find clues of what went wrong in several logs (syslog, daemon, the application's log, etc) but I am not looking for clues, I am looking for the whole command.

[1] I know I can see the command, once the process has started in many ways (ps, pgrep, /proc/NNNN/cmdline, top, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the init.d scripts, located in my distro under /etc/init.d.  On RHEL/Centos, chkconfig and service will use scripts at that location, if they conform to a certain format, to manage services.